# how to add key and certificatio to my soapRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I have a Soap request to make and I have to use a key and certification
How can I integrate it here?
Thanks

```
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = 'the_url';
const headers = {,
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
};
const xml = fs.readFileSync('my_xml_file.xml', 'utf-8');

(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest(url, headers, xml, 1000); 
  const { body, statusCode } = response;
  console.log(body);
  console.log(statusCode);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using another soap module such as `soap`.

You can find exactly what you want here: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientsslsecurity

You simply have to instantiate a client and then add the security options:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url)
client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity('/path/to/key', 'path/to/cert', '/path/to/ca-cert'));
```